# swing: activate a certain input method by default

Tags: java, swing, localization, internationalization, ime

Currently, when using a java input method framework (installed as JRE extension - http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/InputMethod/index.html) in swing applications, our users always have to manually activate the input method either by using hotkey or selecting from the application system menu. They found it very annoyed and wanted to get rid of it. They want the input method must be activated whenever they launch the program.

Does anybody know how to programatically choose and activate an input method (which we know in advance what it is)?

PS.

- This question is a continuation of this one: [Input method menu item is not displayed on system menu of swing app on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633204/input-method-menu-item-is-not-displayed-on-system-menu-of-swing-app-on-ubuntu)
- Our users use Ubuntu desktop, and we cannot use IBus with swing due to this issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/481656 that's why we came with java input method framework solution.

Comment: this is very old framework, take look at todays code and implemented in Oracle APIs

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what is the today-Oracle APIs for solving this i18n data entry?


I've just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903666/changing-ime-language-in-java-swing-application It could be a solution for my problem. Regarding to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/imf/spec.html: **one InputContext instance is created per Window instance, and this input context is shared by all components within the window's containment hierarchy**, thus, I need to call to selectInputMethod method on every new JFrame or JDialog instance, hard work but works.

Comment: [I'd be start with](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-automatic-i18n.html), not sure, but I think that project must be re_compiled after properties file changed,